# streaming with HLS / hevc / fmp4

Tags: ffmpeg, hls, h.265

demo site:
http://47.254.74.168:8080/

I made some streaming of HLS/HEVC/FMP4 by ffmpeg(5.1), which list is above link.
however, the streaming encoded with h265 codec is not working in safari, and h264 is fine.

Don't know why, any ideas? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

H254 HEVC is barely compactible with Safari and Microsoft Edge browsers
https://www.lambdatest.com/web-technologies/hevc

Verify that you have Safari for iOS (version 11.0 and later).